# Seafile can't run for ccnet daemon Error

Tags: command-line, server

What can I do if seafile can't run throwing ccnet daemon error?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use these commands:

```
ccnet -c ~/.ccnet -d
seaf-cli start
seaf-cli status
```

Line 1 runs ccnet as a daemon (a background process)
Line 2 starts seafile
Line 3 check status

From now on, you can sync your folders.